# How does true/false work in PHP?

Tags: php

I wonder how PHP handles **true/false** comparison internally. 
I understand that true is defined as 1 and false is defined as 0. 
When I do `if("a"){ echo "true";}` it echos "**true**". How does PHP recognize "a" as 1 ?

Comment: It's overly simplistic to say that "true is defined as 1 and false is defined as 0."

Comment: btw. guess what this returns: "false" == true

Answer (score 133, accepted):

This is covered in the PHP documentation for [booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) and [type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean `FALSE` itself
- the integer `0` (zero)
- the float `0.0` (zero)
- the empty string, and the **string `'0'`**
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

**Every other value is considered TRUE**.

Comment: "the programmers community" != sh != bash, etc. And no programming or scripting language I've ever used has the convention that anything non-zero is false (of course this doesn't mean there isn't one, but it's a pretty decent sample set). While I definitely prefer strong typing and can't stand much at all about PHP, 'truthy' and 'falsey' values are very common in languages that allow comparison between what would otherwise be incomparable types, and how truthitude is determined for a given type in a given language can be pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Note that when @MarkByers said 'the string "0"', that's exactly right. For example, the string "00", the string "0.0", "\0", etc. do not similarly come out false.

Comment: You should add to your answer that to check if a var is really a boolean, the strict comparison must be used with the `===` operator, not the common used one `==`.

Answer (score 22):

Because I've visited this page several times, I've decided to post an example (loose) comparison test.

Results:

```
""         -> false
"0"        -> false
"0.0"      -> true
"1"        -> true
"01"       -> true
"abc"      -> true
"true"     -> true
"false"    -> true
"null"     -> true
0          -> false
0.1        -> true
1          -> true
1.1        -> true
-42        -> true
"NAN"      -> true
0          -> false
NAN        -> true
null       -> false
true       -> true
false      -> false
[]         -> false
[""]       -> true
["0"]      -> true
[0]        -> true
[null]     -> true
["a"]      -> true
{}         -> true
{}         -> true
{"t":"s"}  -> true
{"c":null} -> true
```

Test code:

```js
class Vegetable {}

class Fruit {
    public $t = "s";
}

class Water {
    public $c = null;
}

$cases = [
    "",
    "0",
    "0.0",
    "1",
    "01",
    "abc",
    "true",
    "false",
    "null",
    0,
    0.1,
    1,
    1.1,
    -42,
    "NAN",
    (float) "NAN",
    NAN,
    null,
    true,
    false,
    [],
    [""],
    ["0"],
    [0],
    [null],
    ["a"],
    new stdClass(),
    new Vegetable(),
    new Fruit(),
    new Water(),
];

echo "<pre>" . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($cases as $case) {
    printf("%s -> %s" . PHP_EOL, str_pad(json_encode($case), 10, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT), json_encode( $case == true ));
}
```

Summary:

- When a strict (`===`) comparison is done, everything except `true` returns `false`.
- an empty string (`""`) is falsy
- a string that contains only `0` (`"0"`) is falsy
- `NAN` is truthy
- an empty array (`[]`) is falsy
- a container (array, object, string) that contains a falsy value is truthy

  - an exception to this is `0` in `""` (see the third item)

Comment: ["false"] -> true, been chewing my foot off over that one today.

Comment: It's freaking stupid to consider `'0'` as `false`, but `'false'` not

Answer (score 11):

Zero is false, nonzero is true.

In php you can test more explicitly using the [`===`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator.

```
if (0==false) 
    echo "works"; // will echo works

if (0===false) 
    echo "works"; // will not echo anything
```

Comment: why `0 === false` won't work?
Also is there a difference between  `0 === false` and `0 === FALSE`?

Comment: There is no difference between `0 === false` and `0 === FALSE`. Both falses evaluate to the same value; for function names and language keywords, PHP is, obnoxiously, case-insensitive. Both of these "work," but they evaluate to false, because `===` actually does a type-dependent value check. `==` allows checks between types; see the accepted answer on this thread for how PHP determines what matches false and what doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

The best operator for strict checking is

```
if($foo === true){}
```

That way, you're really checking if its true, and not 1 or simply just set.

Answer (score 2):

PHP uses weak typing (which it calls 'type juggling'), which is a bad idea (though that's a conversation for another time).  When you try to use a variable in a context that requires a boolean, it will convert whatever your variable is into a boolean, according to some mostly arbitrary rules available here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: That "bad idea" is purely subjective : once you know how this works, it is absolutly not a problem, in my opinion ;-)  ;; and the conversion rules mostly don't seem quite un-logical to me ;-)

Comment: Don't make me post a stackoverflow question about how bad an idea weak typing is ;).  Consider that php manages to make a basic syllogism fail, because implicit type conversions make php equality non-transitive:

echo ("true" == true)."\n"; //true
echo (true == 1)."\n"; // true
echo ("true" == 1)."\n"; // false :P

Comment: Yeah... it's a (potentially) very dangerous trick for new players, but not necessarily a bad idea. I'm not going to defend the robustness of code here, but sometimes it is a nice shortcut. Besides, if you're doing much in the way of larger scale work you'll probably use equality methods most of the time instead.

Answer (score 2):

think of operator as unary function: `is_false(type value)` which returns true or false, depending on the exact implementation for specific type and value.  Consider if statement to invoke such function implicitly, via syntactic sugar.

other possibility is that type has cast operator, which turns type into another type implicitly, in this case string to Boolean.

PHP does not expose such details, but C++ allows operator overloading which exposes fine details of operator implementation.