# IMPORTANCE OF LOGICAL NOT IN PHP

Tags: php

Is it same in PHP:

```
if($x!=5)
{
 //code
}
```

VS

```
$x=5;
if(!$x)
{
 //code
}
```

What about if($x)? Expression in IF statement evaluates to either TRUE or FALSE unlike C where it is either 0 or anything other than 0 (say 1 or more). We can test the expression by using var_dump(!$x) in PHP. So,what about if($x)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php

Comment: There is absolutely no relation between the two,

Answer (score 0):

No,it is not same in PHP:

Logical Operator.

> ! $x  Not TRUE if $x is not
>   TRUE.

Comparison Operators

> ```
> $x!=5  Not equal  TRUE if $x is not equal to 5
> ```

Source: PHP Documentation.

Comment: You don't need to complicate something that easy!

Comment: Then blame the PHP documentation.

Comment: @SobinAugustine yeah,I understand that,but what I mean to say that they can be used in same context,although they are different..right? thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.

The first block of code tests whether or not the variable x does not equal 5.

The 2nd block of code tests whether x is not true.  Since you declared a value for $x, the statement will be evaluated as false and the content inside the brackets will not execute.