# Why should I write !== false instead of ==true?

Tags: testing, boolean

I often see scripts testing if a variable is different from FALSE.

This is an example from php man of "fgetcsv" function, but I think I saw that on Java too.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    //...
}
```

Even if it doesn't change much, it would seem more natural to go like :

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) === TRUE) {
    //...
}
```

Is there a reason the second code is less logic or less efficient ?

Comment: [Null vs. False vs. 0 in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137487/null-vs-false-vs-0-in-php) and [How does true/false work in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common idiom of PHP is to have a function return some meaningful value, or a boolean `FALSE` in case of some failure. In [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)'s case, an index array is returned or `FALSE` when there are no more values to return.

Using `=== TRUE` simply won't work here - an indexed array isn't a boolean `TRUE`, but it is most definitively `!== FALSE`.

Comment: OK, very clear answer. So this is specific to PHP and languages that share this logic. Thanks.