# Optional parameters to Laravel Mail

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

**Create *optional* message parts to Laravel's Mail function?**

E.g. either adding attachment or having bcc.

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($pathToFile); <========= OPTIONAL =========
});
```

I REALLY want to avoid ugly code like this

```
if (isset($data['attachment'])) {
    // Attachment
    Mail::queue('emails.raw', ['content' => $content], function($message) use ($data) {
        $message
            ->subject($data['subject'])
            ->attach($data['attachment'])
            ->to($data['email'])
            ->bcc($data['bcc']);
        });
}
else{
    // No attachment
    Mail::queue('emails.raw', ['content' => $content], function($message) use ($data) {
        $message
            ->subject($data['subject'])
            ->to($data['email'])
            ->bcc($data['bcc']);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just move the if condition into the closure:

```
Mail::queue('emails.raw', ['content' => $content], function($message) use ($data) {
    $message
        ->subject($data['subject'])
        ->to($data['email'])
        ->bcc($data['bcc']);

    if (isset($data['attachment'])) {
        $message->attach($data['attachment']);
    }
});
```

Note that the chaining of methods just syntactical sugar. The above is equivalent to:

```
Mail::queue('emails.raw', ['content' => $content], function($message) use ($data) {
    $message->subject($data['subject']);
    $message->to($data['email']);
    $message->bcc($data['bcc']);

    if (isset($data['attachment'])) {
        $message->attach($data['attachment']);
    }
});
```

So write it however you like.

Comment: Works like a charm! I did not realize I need to have the inner part set to message, tried just ->attach($pathToFile); before. Thanks Jeroen - saved my day!

Comment: You're missing semicolons in your code for $message->subject($data['subject']) and $message->to($data['email'])

Comment: Thank you @PaulDenisevich for paying attention :) Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the part where you are currently adding the from/to etc is simply just a function like any other, it's just that it's referred to as an anonymous function, as it has no defined name.

Therefore, you can just place your conditional logic within the function:

```
$body = 'YOUR_BODY_HERE';
$attachment = 'YOUR_ATTACHMENT_FILEPATH_HERE';

Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['content' => $body], function($message) use ($attachment)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    if ($attachment) {
        $message->attach($attachment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Out of curiosity would not your 'if ($attachment)' need to be TRUE to work? Should it not be 'if (isset($attachment))'?

Comment: Remember that in PHP it can evaluate all variables as "truthy/falsey" (see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php).

My code is assuming that if you didn't have an attachment, then you would have set the `$attachment` variable to be either null or an empty string - and therefore it will have been defined

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, would you mind up-voting please!