# PHP - array_search not working as expected - works then fails

Tags: php

So I have the following:

```
    echo array_search('Resolved at Tier 1', array_column($getHighLevelOverviewPeriodsArray, 'status'));
    print_r($getHighLevelOverviewPeriodsArray);

    if (!array_search('Resolved at Tier 1', array_column($getHighLevelOverviewPeriodsArray, 'status'))) {
        $resolved = array('status' => 'Resolved at Tier 1', 'amount' => 0);
        array_splice($getHighLevelOverviewPeriodsArray, 0, 0, array($resolved));
    }
    print_r($getHighLevelOverviewPeriodsArray);
```

The echo spits out a zero which is right. It does exist in the first place. However the second part runs (if statement) and the `array_splice` gets executed. The output of print_r is below.

What is it being executed even though it's there?

I have the exact same code for Tier 2, character for character (expect for the 2) and that works as expected.

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Resolved at Tier 1
            [amount] =&gt; 10
        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Resolved at Tier 2
            [amount] =&gt; 7
        )

    [2] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Resolved Total
            [amount] =&gt; 17
        )

    [3] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Phone Calls
            [amount] =&gt; 0
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Resolved at Tier 1
            [amount] =&gt; 0
        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Resolved at Tier 1
            [amount] =&gt; 10
        )

    [2] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Resolved at Tier 2
            [amount] =&gt; 7
        )

    [3] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Resolved Total
            [amount] =&gt; 17
        )

    [4] =&gt; Array
        (
            [status] =&gt; Phone Calls
            [amount] =&gt; 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Why do you have array($resolved) at the end of your spliced statement instead of just $resolved since $resolved is already an array?

Comment: That's what I saw had to be done but regardless of that - the search still isn't working

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: No errors. Nothing in logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does true/false work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the warning in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php. 0 == false after type juggling. You need:

```
 if (false !== array_search ...
```

instead of:

```
 if (!array_search...
```

edit to add: Tier 2 works as expected, because indexes greater than zero are 'truthy'.

Comment: if (false === array_search seems to have sorted it