# Check the date between two dates

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-difference

I have to check if the incoming date is between 3 and 6 months before today. If it is outside this range, it has to execute certain code.

below is the code

```
<?php

$date1 = '22-10-2017';
$date2 = date('d-m-Y' , strtotime('-3 months'));
$date3 = date('d-m-Y' , strtotime('-6 months'));
if((strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)) || (strtotime($date1) > strtotime($date3))){
    echo "Inside Range";
}else echo "Out of Range";

?>
```

For example if

1. Incoming date is 20-02-2018 - Out of Range.
2. Incoming date is 20-10-2017 - Inside Range.
3. Incoming date is 20-08-2017 - Out of Range.

Comment: You want to check if the incoming date greater than 3 months from today but you dont have a variable which returns today date

Comment: @Tarasovych Why would that be necessary?

Comment: Is the code in the question working? Why not? What is happening? Any errors?

Comment: @mike : No, it always goes out of range,

Comment: @Mike I guess if you want to compare one variable with another, you have to initialise both, don't you?

Comment: @Tarasovych : Date function will take care of it. date('d-m-Y');

Comment: @Tarasovych You're not comparing to today's date. You're comparing to 3 months and 6 months ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking with `||`  in your case you need to use `&&` because you need date **BETWEEN**

```
$date1 = '20-08-2017';
$date2 = date('d-m-Y' , strtotime('-3 months'));
$date3 = date('d-m-Y' , strtotime('-6 months'));
if((strtotime($date1) <= strtotime($date2)) && (strtotime($date1) >= strtotime($date3))){
    echo "Inside Range";
}else { 
   echo "Out of Range";
}
```

Explanation: 
Need to change your condition from `if((strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)) || (strtotime($date1) > strtotime($date3)))` to `if((strtotime($date1) <= strtotime($date2)) && (strtotime($date1) >= strtotime($date3))){`

It's also significantly easier if you're using DateTime objects:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('20-08-2017');
$date2 = new DateTime('-3 months');
$date3 = new DateTime('-6 months');

if($date1 < $date2 && $date1 > $date3) {
    echo "Inside Range";
} else {
    echo "Out of Range";
}
```

Comment: best to place that  `else` be in braces. I know the OP didn't, but they should and it should be corrected.

Comment: It's also significantly easier if you're using DateTime objects. Mind if I hijack your answer to add that in?

Comment: you are welcome @Mike , i just tried to solve hemanth's problem with his own code... but providing best approach is always welcome

Comment: Adding to it would be good; only hope the answer won't be overwritten though.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I wouldn't do that... :)

Comment: I didn't think  you would @Mike - that's why I didn't ping you in that comment. I was going to, but then said (*Nah...*), he knows what he's doing ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Mike. That was of great help.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I was working on my own answer when this one was posted that was basically the same as it using `DateTime` which didn't really warrant posting another answer, so I thought "why let this quality 7 lines of code just go to waste?"

Comment: Hey @Mike hope things are still rockin' over your way. I'll get that (apparently amazing) cup of coffee from you somehow/day ;-) *cheers* (Krish: pardon my bit of hijacking here).  ...and as I was typing this out while you were also,...... I was going to say that too, in asking why you weren't posting an answer of your own.... oh well.. you got a little something a couple of minutes ago ;-) Gee... wonder what huh?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah, it was this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776512/why-this-result-in-php/48776593#48776593. Weird how stupid answers like that end up getting so many upvotes sometimes...

Comment: @Mike hey, every little bit helps! everybody's happy in the end ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$today=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
$date=date_create("2018-06-12");
$diff=date_diff($today,$date)->format("%a");

if ($diff > 90 && $diff < 180) {
    echo "Inside range";
}
else {
    echo "Out of range";
}
```

Comment: You have the wrong variable names in your `date_diff` function and you also cannot convert a `DateInterval` to Int. You need to `format()` it. See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php