# Why do I not get True when I type 2 or 3 at the Python console?

Tags: python

In Python, any non-zero value is evaluated as True. So, for example, the following code prints `Yes`.

```
if 2 or 3:
    print('Yes')
```

But, if I type `2 or 3` at the Python console I get `2` instead of `True`. Why the different behavior?

Comment: or returns the first truthy value it encounters. In particular, it does not implicitly casts it to a boolean

Comment: `if 2: print('Yes')` also prints "Yes", but you wouldn't expect `print(2)` to print "True", would you?

Comment: Based on the above two comments- should I then infer the following: (a) Typing something at the console is the equivalent of a issuing a print and (b) Python interprets a truthy-value as True only in the context of if statements. Or maybe, I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Both (a) and (b) are wrong.

Comment: In all your cases the `2 or 3` expression is producing `2`.  It is then either displayed directly by the console, passed to the `print` function, or passed to the `if` statement.  The `if` does its own truthiness testing.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. That really helped clarify what is going on. Would you mind converting that to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all your cases the `2 or 3` expression is producing `2`.

It is then either displayed directly by the console, passed to the `print` function, or passed to the `if` statement.

The `if` does its own truthiness testing.

```
In [14]: 2 or 3          # or returns the first truthy item
Out[14]: 2
In [15]: None or 3
Out[15]: 3
In [16]: False or 0 or 2
Out[16]: 2
```

`print` just displays its argument:

```
In [17]: print(2 or 3)
2
```

`if` does the action if its argument if truthy; does the `else` if not:

```
In [18]: if 2: print('yes')
yes
In [19]: if False: print('yes')
```

Here it evaluates the `or`, and then acts on the result:

```
In [20]: if None or 2 or 3: print('yes')
yes
```

---

`and` returns the first falsy, or last if none

```
In [21]: 2 and 3
Out[21]: 3
In [22]: 2 and False
Out[22]: False
In [23]: 2 and 0 and 3
Out[23]: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `or`, Python will return the first truthy value.

```
print None or 2 #  Prints 2
print 0 or 'Foo' # Prints Foo
print False or True # Prints True
```

If the first value is falsy, it will return the second one, actually no matter if it's truthy or not:

```
print None or False #  Prints False
print False or None # Prints None
print False or 0 # Prints 0
```

If you chain the statements, it will evaluate the first condition first, then the second

```
print None or False or 0 # Will evaluate into ((None or False) or 0)
```

This is also possible in languages like [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382510/10400050) and [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35642837/10400050).

---

**Source**: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 1):

`or` returns the first value if the value is *truthy*, or the second value if the first value is *falsy* ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)).

This behavior is sometimes used idiomatically to initialize keyword argument of mutable type:

```
def foo(bar=None, zoo=None):
    bar = bar or []
    zoo = zoo or {}
```

This is [not the unique way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists) to initialize them, but you should be [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) you should not use empty list or dict as default argument.