# How does PHP handle NULL SQLite fields in an associative result?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Say I have an SQLite table with a field named `someValue`. Say I use PHP to query the table and a row is returned in which `someValue` is NULL.

If I try to reference `$row['someValue']`, what happens? Does PHP return a `null` value, or does it throw an "undefined index"? I can't find this in the documentation. What if I use a numeric index instead of associative? If PHP returns a `null`, is `isset()` true or false?

Bonus: is this handled the same way in other databases like MySQL?

Comment: It usually returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You would get a (fatal?) undefined-index error, if I remember correctly.

& you can avoid this by using:

```
if(!empty($row)&&!empty($row['someValue'])){
  echo $row['someValue']
}
```

This way we check `$row` first, before checking `$row['someValue']` because in php conditions in if-statements are "greedy", returning once a result is found, rather than parsing all conditions.

I prefer using `!empty()` to using `isset()` because in my experience it's more reliable. I'll spare you the essay, [but here's the concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php), sometimes things are true when they're not & vice vera.

As per [Lou's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7442890/lou), if I run `if( isset('') )` I recieve the following error:

`Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

... but if I use `if( !empty('') )` it works.