# php arrays in arrays - does it contain this string

Tags: php, arrays

I have what looks like a rather strange array, to me anyway, this is the result of a print_r ($info) and of var_export; :

```
print_r ($info);
```

*output*

```
Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => 
Array ( [sessiontimeout] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => 0 ) [0] => sessiontimeout [description] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => Admin group ) [1] => description [cn] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => ldap-admin ) [2] => cn [objectclass] => Array ( [count] => 2 [0] => top [1] => GroupV2 ) [3] => objectclass [enabled] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => TRUE ) [4] => enabled [uniquemember] => Array ( [count] => 2 [0] => uid=username1,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net [1] => uid=username2,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net )
[5] => uniquemember [count] => 6 [dn] => cn=ldap-admin,cn=staff,cn=company,cn=groups,dc=abc,dc=net ) )
```

```
var_export($info);
array ( 'count' => 1, 0 => array ( 'sessiontimeout' => array ( 'count' => 1, 0 => '0', ), 0 => 'sessiontimeout', 'description' => array ( 'count' => 1, 0 => 'Admin group', ), 1 => 'description', 'cn' => array ( 'count' => 1, 0 => 'ldap-admin', ), 2 => 'cn', 'objectclass' => array ( 'count' => 2, 0 => 'top', 1 => 'oGroupV2', ), 3 => 'objectclass', 'enabled' => array ( 'count' => 1, 0 => 'TRUE', ), 4 => 'enabled', 'uniquemember' => array ( 'count' => 2, 0 => 'uid=username1,cn=users,dc=jhc,dc=net', 1 => 'uid=username2,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net', ), 5 => 'uniquemember', 'count' => 6, 'dn' => 'cn=ldap-admin,cn=staff,cn=company,cn=groups,dc=abc,dc=net', ), )
```

im only interested in the uniquemember uid= parts. I have been trying to set a variable that is  uid=usernameX and then check if the variable contains the username i have been given previously in my code. It looks like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$info["count"]; $i++) {
  $uid = $info[$i]["uniquemember"][$i];

  if (strpos($info, "uid=$username")) {
    echo "$username  valid";
  } else {
    echo $username not valid";
  }
}
```

As far as i can tell my variable uid is not being reset to the second instance of uid=, in this case it should be "uid=username2"

If the username provided is username1 i get the output

```
username1 valid
```

If the username is username2 i get

```
username2 not valid
```

When i would expect it to be valid.

Comment: What is `$info[$]`? Did you mean to put a variable in there?

Comment: `$i<=$info["count"]` should probably be only `<` without the `=`

Comment: `var_export($info)` into your question might facilitate reproducing the issue

Comment: @JeremyHarris typo - edited to fix. -dWinder Thats what i had to start but it didnt make a difference. -jibsteroos looks very similar to print_r output but ive added to question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be useful if you break it up into smaller parts so you can more clearly see what is happening. One thing to note is that `strpos` can return 0 if it matches on the first char (which it will) and the way you are writing the if statement, its only checking for [truthy or falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php). Change it to use `!== false` for a proper comparison.

```php
// Get unique members array
$uniqueMembers = $info[0]['uniquemember'];

// Get unique member count
$memberCount = (int) $uniqueMembers['count'];

// Loop through members
for ($i = 0; $i < $memberCount; $i++) {

    // Get the UID string
    $uid = $uniqueMembers[$i];

    // Check if it matches the supplied username
    if (strpos($uid, "uid=$username") !== false) {
       echo "$username is valid!";
    } else {
       echo "$username is not valid!";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @jeremy, i think a dollar is missing in the $memberCount variable? Also it seems to work where the username matches $uid but because it loops through i am getting it also return $username is not valid when it compares the second username to the username given?

Comment: Ah, yep, fixed. You can simply add a `break()` in the condition where you find a valid user to exit the loop.