# remove an index from array if a variable does not have value laravel php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have an array like below :

```
 $attributeOptionsData[] = [
                    'id'           => $optionId,
                    'label'        => $attributeOption->label ? $attributeOption->label : $attributeOption->admin_name,
                    'swatch_value' => $attribute->swatch_type == 'image' ? $attributeOption->swatch_value_url : $attributeOption->swatch_value,
                    'products'     => $options[$attribute->id][$optionId],
                    'images'     => $productImage ?? null,
                ];
```

i simply want to instead of null safe the `images` if the `$productImage` does not have value remove it from the array i mean remove `images` completely is that possible ??

Comment: You can use `array_filter` to remove all _FALSE_ values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` without any callbacks to remove all *falsey* values (null, false, 0, '', etc.)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382510/296555

```
<?php
$attributeOptionsData[] = [
    'id'           => 'someValue',
    'label'        => 'someValue',
    'swatch_value' => 'someValue',
    'products'     => 'someValue',
    'images'       => null,
];

$filteredList = array_filter($attributeOptionsData[0]);

var_dump($filteredList);
// array(4) {
//   ["id"]=> string(9) "someValue"
//   ["label"]=> string(9) "someValue"
//   ["swatch_value"]=> string(9) "someValue"
//   ["products"]=> string(9) "someValue"
// }
```

This is also a neat function.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091

> If you want a quick way to remove NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings (""),
> but leave values of 0 (zero), you can use the standard php function
> strlen as the callback function: eg:
>
> ```
> <?php
>  
> // removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero)
> values $result = array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );
>
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `array_splice`

```
<?php

if (empty($attributeOptionsData[0]['images'])) {

  array_splice($attributeOptionsData[0], 4);
}

print_r($attributeOptionsData[0]);

/*Result
Array
(
    [id] => $optionId
    [label] => $attributeOption->label ? $attributeOption->label : $attributeOption->admin_name
    [swatch_value] => $attribute->swatch_type ==  ? $attributeOption->swatch_value_url : $attributeOption->swatch_value
    [products] => $options[$attribute->id][$optionId]
)
*/
```

Comment: OP's code is a multi-dimensional array `$attributeOptionsData[] = [...`

Comment: It's multidimensional but with only index 0, alredy fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your array will not only contain 1 element, in case it has only 1 element, just remove foreach loop.
Below is my solution for this.

```
    $attributeOptionsData[] = [
        'id'           => 'string',
        'label'        => 'var',
        'swatch_value' => '123',
        'products'     => '',
        'images'       => null,
    ];

    $attributeOptionsData[] = [
        'id'           => 1,
        'label'        => '2',
        'swatch_value' => null,
        'products'     => '',
        'images'       => null,
    ];


    foreach($attributeOptionsData as $key => $value)
    {
        $attributeOptionsData[$key] = array_filter($attributeOptionsData[$key]);
    }

    //$attributeOptionsData now will be your result;
```

Your result will look like this:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => "string",
    "label" => "var",
    "swatch_value" => "123",
  ],
  1 => [
    "id" => 1,
    "label" => "2",
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

this one will remove images but will not change index number

```
$vr = count($attributeOptionsData);
for ($i=0; $i < $vr; $i++) { 
  if (empty($attributeOptionsData[i]['images'])) {
    unset($attributeOptionsData[i]['images']);
  }
}
```