# How to use ternary operator in php?

Tags: php, ternary

When I use ternary operator in PHP I realize that

```
0, '0',and null is null
```

so this is little strange, in my opinion that this value '0' considered as a string and no longer considered as null, but the result in ternary this will return to `null` value

maybe this will be help you

```
$a=0
$b='0'
$c=null

$a??'it is null'
//it is null
$b??'it is null'
//it is null
$c??'it is null'
//it is null

$a==null?'it is null':'not null'
//it is null
$b==null?'it is null':'not null'
//it is null
$c==null?'it is null':'not null'
//it is null
```

so what I want to ask is, how can I make that '0' is not a null value in ternary PHP

Comment: please take a read on [php falsy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php)

Comment: _"how can i make that '0' is not a null value in ternary php"_ - You don't need to do anything. It's the default behavior. Just like `$a ??` and `$b ?? ` won't evaluate as `null`. https://3v4l.org/sHVXk. And if you want to do a type safe comparison, use three `===` instead of two `==`.

Comment: oke i understand now thanks

Comment: It is only JavaScript which may deliver questionable results is some situations, PHP is rather accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is deeper than the ternary operator.

## Boolean logic

Boolean logic recognizes true and false values, defines relations and operations with these, builds the Boolean algebra upon logical values and their operations.

PHP (and other languages) supports boolean values of `true` and `false`

## Truey and falsy

If

```
$a === true
```

then `$a` is `true`.

If

```
$a == true
```

then `$a` is truey. For example, `1` is not `true`, but it is still truey.

If

```
$b === false
```

then `$b` is `false`. If

```
$b == false
```

then `$b` is falsy. For example, `0` is falsy, but it is not `false`.

You wonder about `'0'` not being false/falsy. However, logically, the most false string value is `''`, which is empty string. `'0'` is longer than `''`. `'false'` is also a string and different from `false`.

## Ternary operator

```
$a ? $b : $c
```

evaluates whether `$a` is truey. If so, then the expression's result is `$b`. Otherwise the expression's result is `$c`.

Comment: This reads as if other languages would support "maybe".

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for pointing out that ambivalence. Edited my answer accordingly.